# Haskell - Print tree data: Non-exhaustive patterns in function toList

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming

I have a `tree` that is represented by a data structure:

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) (Tree a)| Leaf a

t1 :: Tree Int
t1 = (Node (Node (Leaf 23) (Leaf 42)) (Node (Leaf 19) (Leaf 65)))
```

Now I need to print the data of the leaves:

```
toList :: Tree a -> [a]
toList (Node (Leaf a) (Leaf b))       = [a] ++ [b]
toList (Node (Leaf a) (Node x y))     = [a] ++ (toList (Node x y))
toList (Node (Node x y) (Leaf b))     = (toList (Node x y)) ++ [b]
```

Unfotunately I keep getting the error:

> Non-exhaustive patterns in function toList

However I am using parentheses.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What about two `Node`s?

Comment: Enabling warnings with `-Wall` would have 1) signaled this at compile time instead of runtime, 2) pointed out the case(s) which are not matched. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you can call `toList` with a value, and **all your lines will fail to fire**.

This is the case when I call your script with **two `Node`s**: `toList (Node (Node x y) (Node z t))`. In that case all lines will fail. You probably want to add the line:

```
toList (Node (Node x y) (Node z t)) = (toList (Node x y))++(toList (Node x y))
```

or a bit shorter:

```
toList (Node a@(Node _ _) b@(Node _ _)) = (toList a)++(toList b)
```

another one is a **single `Leaf`**: `toList (Leaf x)`:

```
toList (Leaf x) = [x]
```

This being said you make things overcomplicated. You can simply use two lines:

```
toList :: Tree a -> [a]
toList (Leaf x) = [x]
toList (Node x y) = toList x ++ toList y
```

It is very easy to see that here all cases are covered since there are only two data constructors and we do not put pattern constraints on their arguments.

Comment: No, it _is_ an error! It is precisely what GHCi prints at runtime when pattern matching fails to find a matching case. The compile-time warning reads "Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive", the run-time error reads "Non-exhaustive patterns in function <name>".